# Division of bivariate polynomials

Tags: polynomials, elimination-theory, resultants

The following theorem (lemma 4.2.18 on page 97) is proven in thesis "Computationally efficient Error-Correcting Codes and Holographic Proofs" by  Daniel Alan Spielman:

Let $E(X, Y)$ be a polynomial of degree ($\alpha m, \beta n$) over some field $\mathbb{F}$
and $P(X, Y)$ be a polynomial of degree ($\alpha m + \delta m, \beta n+\epsilon n$) over the same field. Assume there exist distinct $x_1, \dots, x_m \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $E(x_i, Y)$ divides $P(x_i, Y)$ (as a polynomial in $Y$) for $1 \leq i \leq m$ and distinct $y_1, ... y_n \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $E(X, y_i)$ divides $P(X, y_i)$
(as a polynomial in $X$) for $1 \leq i \leq n$.

If $$\alpha + \beta + \delta + \epsilon < 1\;\;\;\;\;(*)$$ then $E(X, Y)$ divides $P(X,Y)$ in the ring $\mathbb{F}[X, Y]$.

My question is the following: how strict and precise is bound $(*)$? Is there a counterexample to the statement, given that $$\alpha + \beta + \delta + \epsilon \geq 1?$$

I suppose there are some connections with multivariate resultants and elimination theory, so I put them in the tags.

Comment: Hi there, I am also encountering troubles with that theorem from Spielman, but for other reasons. It concerns the multiplicity argument. It rests on the vanishing of derivatives of $R(E,P)$ at $x_i$. This seems insufficient to me, especially in characteristic 2 (such as is the case in the application made within the original FRI paper) where the second derivative of *any* polynomial vanishes. I'm curious whether there is a proof that bypasses the vanishing derivatives argument to justify the large multiplicities and if you know one. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, nevermind! I have a work around that establishes the required multiplicity and does not use derivatives. It follows from some matrix manipulations.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong, my argument doesn't work. Do you know how to fix the multiplicity argument in Spielman's thesis?